# How to tell programmatically if a IBAction has been called by code or by user action

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uisegmentedcontrol, ibaction

How can I tell programmatically if a IBAction has been called by code or by user action.

Eg
I have a method, `-(IBAction)someMethodWithIts:(id)sender`
which I have linked to a valueChanged on a UISegmentedControl.

It can be called by,

1. User changing segment
2. setting the selectedIndex in code
3. calling `[self someMethodWithIts:foo];`

Is there a way to distinguish if the call has come from the first way?

Cheers

Sam

Comment: What will `foo` be in your third method?

Comment: it would be an instance I'd imagine

Comment: An instance of what? You can use that information to distinguish.

Comment: From 1 or 2 the sender will be a pointer to the control.  From 3 it's whatever foo is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can pass `nil` as the sender (which is traditional) and use that to indicate it was sent programmatically, that's ok. But anything else I believe is too fragile and you should break up the code like this:

```
- (void)someMethod {
  // stuff shared by everyone
}

- (IBAction)someMethodWithIts:(id)sender {
  // stuff specific to IBAction
  [self someMethod];
}
```

If you really want a sender, then you can do it this way:

```
- (void)someMethodWithIts:(id)sender triggeredByUser:(BOOL)isUser {
}

- (IBAction)someMethodWithIts:(id)sender {
  [self someMethodWithIts:sender triggeredByUser:YES];
}
```

But in general, if you want the IBAction to be different than programatic changes, then don't wire programatic changes to the IBAction.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([sender isKindOfClass:[UIControl class]]) {
    UIControl *controlSender = (UIControl *)sender;
    if (sender.selected) {
        // then it's #1
    } else {
        // then it's #2
    }
} else if ([sender isKindOfClass:[Foo class]]) {
    // then it's #3
}
```

Might work. Or poke around other properties of sender defined on UIControl or UISegmentedControl. Maybe `state`. My guess is you can find something that's different when the user is interacting vs. when they're not.

Answer (score 0):

You really want to use method like this

```
-(IBAction)actionWithSender:(id)sender event:(UIEvent*)event
{
    if (event) {

    } else {

    }
}
```

If you find the `event` parameter is `nil`, it's from a call in your code, otherwise, the call is from user event.